# Почему не запускается эмулятор в android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Скажите в чем может быть проблема того, что очень долго грузится проект? но в конечном итоге не запускается?
Очень долго грузится так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ничего не открывается.
В чем может быть проблема, куда копать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ничего не открывается.
В чем может быть проблема, куда копать?

Comment: Пишет, что ждёт эмулятор, он запущен и правильно указан?

Comment: Ну так я его и пытаюсь запустить командой cordova run --emulator. И ничего

Comment: А чем встроенные эмуляторы не устраивают?

Comment: А как это сделать?